# How to make component inside a component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components

```
<Modal>
    <Modal.Footer>
        // any custom content. User can completely control behavior of this content. 
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>

export const ModalFooter = ({children}) => {
     return <div className={'modal-footer'}>{children}</div>
}

.modal-footer {
    // css to make footer sticky or scrollable. 
}
```

The scenario is that the footer of the Modal is going to be an optional feature. Only if the person sends <Modal.Footer/>, will that appear. So I want to create <Modal.Footer> inside the modal component.
Can someone please tell me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create like this

```
const Modal = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;

const ModalFooter = ({children}) => {
     return <div className={'modal-footer'}>{children}</div>
}

Modal.Footer = ModalFooter;
export default Modal;
```

Comment: I'm confused. Did you put ModalFooter inside the modal or outside?  And does this technique have any name?

Comment: this is called react components with dot notation https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type